# No data showing when app is hosted on heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongodb-atlas

I have recently tried to deploy my ecommerce store to Heroku.

The app is appearing however none of the information is displaying. I can't use the sign in function either I'm getting a **status code 401.**

Everything appears fine in the localhost.

Im using MongoDB Atlas to host the database.

I've posted the config var to heroku using the following command `heroku config:set MONGODB_URL="mongodb+srv://yourUsername:yourPassword@yourClusterName.n9z04.mongodb.net/sample_mflix?retryWrites=true&w=majority"`  with the relevant information with the relevant information.

Is there a step that I am missing. Should I put the config var somewhere in my source code?

I've also attached the heroku log incase it has some relevant information in it.

```
 2021-01-01T10:24:18.348137+00:00 app[web.1]: Server started at                     
 http://localhost:5000
 2021-01-01T10:24:18.896898+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting           
 to up
 2021-01-01T10:24:30.623315+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" 
 host=honeyman-designs.herokuapp.com request_id=7a2539dc-bb3e-4b8d-b77
 5-4544b2977c8a fwd="79.97.31.121" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30ms 
 status=200 bytes=2506 protocol=https
 2021-01-01T10:24:30.791922+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET 
 path="/static/css/main.5ec8a089.chunk.css" host=honeyman- 
designs.herokuapp.com
request_id=af0fde90-8dbb-4102-ad96-f5e05c44fced fwd="79.97.31.121" dyno=web.1 
 connect=0ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=6148 protocol=https
 2021-01-01T10:24:30.796204+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET 
 path="/static/js/main.8623e411.chunk.js" host=honeyman-designs.herokuapp.com 
 r
 equest_id=f4bc8514-2dde-479b-8934-8f59056ef1cd fwd="79.97.31.121" dyno=web.1 
 connect=1ms service=9ms status=200 bytes=43300 protocol=https
 2021-01-01T10:24:30.918639+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET 
 path="/static/js/2.8114b5af.chunk.js" host=honeyman-designs.herokuapp.com 
 requ
 est_id=bcc9933f-20a5-4f55-855d-6f3d5ed38886 fwd="79.97.31.121" dyno=web.1 
 connect=0ms service=13ms status=200 bytes=198152 protocol=https
 2021-01-01T10:24:18.348137+00:00 app[web.1]: Server started at 
 http://localhost:5000
 2021-01-01T10:24:18.896898+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting 
 to up
 2021-01-01T10:24:30.623315+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" 
 host=honeyman-designs.herokuapp.com request_id=7a2539dc-bb3e-4b8d-b77
 5-4544b2977c8a fwd="79.97.31.121" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30ms 
 status=200 bytes=2506 protocol=https
 2021-01-01T10:24:30.791922+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET 
 path="/static/css/main.5ec8a089.chunk.css" host=honeyman- 
designs.herokuapp.com
request_id=af0fde90-8dbb-4102-ad96-f5e05c44fced fwd="79.97.31.121" dyno=web.1 
 connect=0ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=6148 protocol=https
 2021-01-01T10:24:30.796204+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET 
 path="/static/js/main.8623e411.chunk.js" host=honeyman-designs.herokuapp.com 
 r
 equest_id=f4bc8514-2dde-479b-8934-8f59056ef1cd fwd="79.97.31.121" dyno=web.1 
 connect=1ms service=9ms status=200 bytes=43300 protocol=https
 2021-01-01T10:24:30.918639+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET 
 path="/static/js/2.8114b5af.chunk.js" host=honeyman-designs.herokuapp.com 
 requ
 est_id=bcc9933f-20a5-4f55-855d-6f3d5ed38886 fwd="79.97.31.121" dyno=web.1 
 connect=0ms service=13ms status=200 bytes=198152 protocol=https
```

I've used `heroku ps:scale web=1` to check if any dyno's are working and they are I get this message: **Scaling dynos... done, now running web at 1:Free**

**config.js**

```
 import dotenv from 'dotenv';

 dotenv.config();

 export default {
   PORT: process.env.PORT || 5000,
   MONGODB_URL: process.env.MONGODB_URL || 'mongodb://localhost/honeymandesigns',
 }
```

**.env file**

```
 MONGODB_URL=mongodb://localhost/honeymandesigns
```

**server.js**

```
 const mongodbUrl = config.MONGODB_URL;
 mongoose.connect(mongodbUrl, {
 useNewUrlParser: true,
 useUnifiedTopology: true,
 useCreateIndex: true
 }).catch(error => console.log(error.reason));
```

Comment: I don't see any errors in those logs. "The app is appearing however none of the information is displaying"—have you added any data to your database? "I can't use the sign in function"—have you created an account? The data in your local database won't magically appear in your production one (nor should it).

Comment: previously I also encountered similar error. Check is your `username` or `password` which you are using in mongoDB_URL contains any special characters, if so you need to encode them for example if password contains character '$' replace it with '%24' similarly for other special characters. You can check list of characters-set [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP)

Comment: @Sudhir, do you see anything in the log output suggesting that the connection to MongoDB is the problem? OP says the application is working.

Comment: he stated that app runs but infomations doesn't get displayed so I though problem might be in connecting with mongoDB custers. Also he is only logging error.reason not entire error object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just posting as I found the solution to my problem.

The MongoDb Atlas was connected however the data was not migrated to MongoDB atlas.

Once I migrated the data using MongoDB compass to MongoDB Atlas the data then displayed.

I followed along this youtube video to do this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tpz-6Trd1UI&t=12s

Answer (score -1):

Yes,you should have an .env(https://ibb.co/j5kJznb), inside the .env file use
`DB_CONNECT = mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.n0n6r.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

In your index.js require dotenv(https://ibb.co/C2gxk36)

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();
```

Also,connect your database in heroku aswell https://dev.to/cpclark360/how-to-host-a-restful-node-js-server-with-mongodb-atlas-database-on-heroku-1opl

Comment: Hi this still didn't work. I did this in my .enfile
DB_CONNECT=mongodb+srv://honeyman:username@cluster0.vvb95.mongodb.net/dbname?retryWrites=true&w=majority
MONGODB_URL=mongodb://localhost/honeymandesigns

in the server.js I tried 
const db = config.DB_CONNECT;
const mongodbUrl = config.MONGODB_URL;
mongoose.connect(mongodbUrl, db, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useCreateIndex: true
}).catch(error => console.log(error.reason));

Comment: No, you should _not_ have an `.env` file. Those are for local development, not production deployments and should be `.gitignore`d. The  whole point of an `.env` is to simplify setting environment variables in development, but Heroku natively leverages environment variables through its [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars), which OP says they have already set using `heroku config:set`.